# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable) when my REST api call

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, rest

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable) when my REST api call works in site. But when I enter the REST url in browser it returns the result.
So nothing wrong with the URL. I have the following code which I run against SP 2013 environment, I slightly converted this code which was perfectly worked with SP 2010 environment.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.getJSON("siteURL/_api/lists/getbytitle('Laptops')/items?$select=Title,Id", function (data) {
            var html="";
            var count = 0;
            $.each(data.d.results, function(i,result) {
                var title = result.Title;
                html = "<table><tr><td>" + title +"</td></tr> <tr></tr></table>";

                $('#resultarea').append($(html));
            });

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the return results using your browser dev tools -- my environment (using O365 and jquery 1.11.1) returns the results from `$.getJSON(url, function(data) { //do something with data });` in `data.value` no `d`, or `d.results`

This works on my O365 site:

```
$.getJSON("/_api/lists/getbytitle('Laptops')/items?$select=Title,Id", function (data) {
        html = "<table>";
        $.each(data.value, function(i,val) {
            html += "<tr><td>" + val.Title +"</td></tr>";
        });
        html += "</table>";
        $('#resultarea').html(html);
});
```

I took the liberty of optimizing your write routine a little, fewer DOM manipulations are always faster!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why `$.getJSON()` does not work, but `$.ajax()` should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oDataUrl = "siteURL/_api/lists/getbytitle('Laptops')/items?$select=Title,Id";
    $.ajax({
        url: oDataUrl,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var html="";
            var count = 0;
            $.each(data.d.results, function(i,result) {
                var title = result.Title;
                html = "<table><tr><td>" + title +"</td></tr> <tr></tr></table>";

                $('#resultarea').append($(html));
            });
        },
        error: function(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
            alert("An error occurred: " + errorMessage);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined

Comment: Odd, the `odata=verbose` specification should put the items under `data.d.results`.  Put a breakpoint in immediately after the success function, and see what's in `data`.